# Python exits at random times without throwing exception when running OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

First time asking, I havent found any answers to this after some days of looking. Also im absolutely not a programming pro so I might have missed something obvious.

I am running a code that goes through a large library of images (some 2M) and extracts information from them. The code runs fine for several iterations (20-10000ish) but then the program just stops without any errors reported.

The main code exits (terminates?) most of the time at an OpenCV edge detection or houghlines, but not all the time. about 10% of the time it is at some other point in the code.

Using:

OpenCV 4.1.1
Python 3.7.1
Windows 10

Image at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5lfzkw6sqmu73eb/Image_00_00_00_00.bmp?dl=0

I have tried to get an exception from the Opencv code in some ways, but nothing pops up. The latest attempt is in the code below.

I have tried to use the trace and log modules but I cant really get them to do anything useful.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import traceback
import sys


def cropping_points2(img):

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)             # Gray image needed for edge detection
    try: 
        edges = cv2.Canny(gray,20,70,apertureSize = 3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        print(sys.exc_info())
        print(e, 'there was actually an exception!')  
        exit() 
    lines = []

    try:
        lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,3,np.pi/180,65, 50, 10, min_theta = 1.4, max_theta = 1.75)    # analyse image to find lines - thetha setting looks for horizontal

    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        print(sys.exc_info())
        print(e, 'there was actually an exception!')    
        exit() 

    if lines is None:                                                                             # All black images return a NoneType image
        print('no lines!')                                                                      # Capture NoneType without crashiing
        rect = []
        has_lines = False
        return rect , has_lines
    has_lines = True      
    return lines[0][0], has_lines 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    img= cv2.imread('Image_00_00_00_00.bmp')
    for index in range(10000):
        rect, has_lines = cropping_points2(img)
        print(rect)
        print(index)
```

I expect the program to give me a hint of why it stops running =|

Comment: You could put the try block in the main so that you are sure nothing escapes from the functions you call

Comment: Hi Christian, i tried that just now, but still no exception

Comment: When playing around further with this minimal example, I find that excluding the Canny operation (by using an image with edges already), there is no crash after 100k iterations. Also when excluding the houghlines operation (but keeping canny) there is no crash.

Comment: can you start the program from the command line (from a cmd window)?
If yes, can you check the exit code after the program failed. It might give you an indication.

just type
`echo %errorlevel%`
in the cmd window after the program failed

Comment: Thanks gelonida, I got an error number when I ran that: -1073741819. I cant find anything on what to do with that number tho. Any suggestions?

Comment: -1073741819 Access violation.
Indicates that the executed program has terminated abnormally or crashed.